# How do not show imaginary part (0j) if the number is real in Python?

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I would like to display numbers, such that if the number is real only the real part is displayed. (don't show the `0j`)
If it is imaginary, so show only the imaginary part.
If it is complex, so show the real and the imaginary part.

The code output is:

```
k = 251.50+0.00j  
fc0 = 0.00 GHz, beta_n0 = 251.50+0.00j, dist = 3.98+0.00j mm  
fc1 = 9.99 GHz, beta_n1 = 139.24+0.00j, dist = 7.18+0.00j mm  
fc2 = 19.99 GHz, beta_n2 = 0.00+334.97j, dist = 0.00-2.99j mm  
fc3 = 29.98 GHz, beta_n3 = 0.00+575.79j, dist = 0.00-1.74j mm
```

But I want something like this:

```
k = 251.50  
fc0 = 0.00 GHz, beta_n0 = 251.50, dist = 3.98 mm  
fc1 = 9.99 GHz, beta_n1 = 139.24, dist = 7.18 mm  
fc2 = 19.99 GHz, beta_n2 = 334.97j, dist = -2.99j mm  
fc3 = 29.98 GHz, beta_n3 = 575.79j, dist = -1.74j mm
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

The code is below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.constants import c, mu_0, epsilon_0, pi
from cmath import sqrt

c0 = c
eps0 = epsilon_0
mi0 = mu_0

d = 1.5e-2
f = 12e9
eps_r_ = 1
eps_r__ = 0  #2e-3
mi_r = 1

cc = c0/sqrt(eps_r_*mi_r)
k = 2*pi*f/cc

print("k = {0:.2f}".format(k))

for n in range(4):
    fc = n*c0/(2*d)
    beta_n = sqrt((k**2-(n*pi/d)**2))
    print("fc{0} = {1:.2f} GHz, beta_n{0} = {2:.2f}, dist = {3:.2f} mm".format(n,fc*1e-9,beta_n,1/beta_n*1e3))
```

Comment: How should `0+0j` be shown? `0` or `0j`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to NOT print the j in Python complex numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597321/how-to-not-print-the-j-in-python-complex-numbers)

Comment: Beside the point, but a bunch of that code is unused: `np`, `eps0`, `epsilon_0`, `mi0`, `mu_0`, and `c`. For `c`, you might want to do `import c as c0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit from the `complex` type:

```py
In [1]: class MyComplex(complex):
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         if self.imag == 0:
   ...:             return str(self.real)
   ...:         elif self.real == 0:
   ...:             return str(self.imag) + 'j'
   ...:         else:
   ...:             return super(MyComplex, self).__repr__()
   ...:
In [2]: MyComplex(0)
Out[2]: 0.0

In [3]: MyComplex(0+0j)
Out[3]: 0.0

In [4]: MyComplex(1+0j)
Out[4]: 1.0

In [5]: MyComplex(1j)
Out[5]: 1.0j

In [6]: MyComplex(1+1j)
Out[6]: (1+1j)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Yes, it's a good solution, but I think there may be some more direct way to do this print, without having to create a class.